# Python Spark- How to output empty DataFrame to csv file (Only output header)?

Tags: csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to output empty dataframe to csv file. I use these codes:

```
df.repartition(1).write.csv(path, sep='\t', header=True)
```

But due to there is no data in dataframe, spark won't output header to csv file.
Then I modify the codes to:

```
if df.count() == 0:
    empty_data = [f.name for f in df.schema.fields]
    df = ss.createDataFrame([empty_data], df.schema)
    df.repartition(1).write.csv(path, sep='\t')
else:
    df.repartition(1).write.csv(path, sep='\t', header=True)
```

It works, but I want to ask whether there are a better way without count function.

Comment: Not sure why df.schema is being passed to createDataFrame. If you have anything other than strings in your schema the method call will break.

Answer (score 2):

`df.count() == 0` will make your driver program retrieve the count of all your dataframe partitions across the executors.

In your case I would use `df.take(1).isEmpty` (Spark >= 2.1). Still slow, but preferable to a raw `count()`.

Answer (score 1):

Only header:

```
cols = '\t'.join(df.columns)
with open('./cols.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(cols)
```

Comment: The file may be not in local system. I use Azure HDInsight and blob storage.